# Why do people use “mayday” and not “help”?

Tags: etymology, terminology

I’m not native English speaker, so I wonder why forces like policemen and firemen and such use  *Mayday* instead of the simpler *Help*. What is origin of this habit?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSdxqIBfEAw

Comment: Voting to close as General Reference.

Comment: @Jeremy: I didn't say it was off-topic, I closed it as General Reference: "_This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information._"

Comment: @Jeremy: No prob. :)

Comment: @Alenanno - I'm sorry, but what did you mean by "General Reference"? I don't see what I did wrong.

Comment: Read my second comment, I pasted the definition.

Comment: @Alenanno - Call me stupid, but I couldn't find why they are using mayday and not help. I admit I might did mistake by asking "what is origin..."

Comment: Yeah, you were right. Only that part was GenRef. But don't worry, it's just one vote for now, I think it will stay open (you need 5 votes to close a question). If people will find it ok, it will stay open.

Comment: @ Alenanno Well, if this question is not suitable for this site, I don't mind closing it. But I would like to be told what I did wrong, so I don't do the very same mistake in the future. From now on, I'll try not to make questions which can be classified as "General Reference". :]

Comment: @StupidOne: One thing to help you write a better question: do a little research on your own. If you can show that you found some information on your own, then people won't be able to close as GenRef so easily. For example, in this case, if you had searched "mayday origins" or something similar, you could have dug up some history. Then, based on what you found, you could ask a question that needed some higher level of analysis or thinking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mayday comes from the french *venez m'aider*, which translates to "come help me". This was simply formalized as official in the 1940s. Any other phrase could have been used; mayday is just what stuck.

Technical terms like "mayday" have several advantages over just use an already existing common term like "help!":

1. It may have a slightly different definition than any existing common word. This isn't particularly true for "mayday", although I think using "mayday" instead of "help" indicates someone is a member of whatever field and therefore can be treated as such during the rescue.
2. A common term like "help" can be used in all sorts of situations, so someone saying help on the radio might cause confusion; they might not be calling for help, there are lots of situations someone would just say the word. Yelling "mayday mayday mayday" on a radio isn't ambiguous; everyone immediately knows that this is a call for help.
3. Specialists like to be cool by having their own languages.

Answer (score 8):

I think [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayday_%28distress_signal%29) explains everything. I quote here the corresponding paragraph of the article in Wikipedia:

> The Mayday callsign was originated in 1923 by Frederick Stanley Mockford (1897–1962). A senior radio officer at Croydon Airport in London, Mockford was asked to think of a word that would indicate distress and would easily be understood by all pilots and ground staff in an emergency. Since much of the traffic at the time was between Croydon and Le Bourget Airport in Paris, he proposed the word "Mayday" from the French m’aider. "Venez m'aider" means "come help me."